# Преобразование метода в Func<TRes>

Tags: c#

Как преобразуется метод, что можно использовать `Func<TResult>`? И почему `Func<TResult>` требует статических полей или методов?

```
Func<int> func = () => Factorial(5);

static int Factorial(int x) {
    int result = 1;
    for(int i = 1;i <= x;i++)
        result *= i;
    return result;
}
```

Comment: `Func<int>` этот тип, значением такого типа может быть любая функция, которая не принимает ничего на входе и возвращает int. Такой функцией в вашем коде является это `() => Factorial(5)`

Comment: `И почему Func"TResult" требует статических полей или методов?` это заблуждение, нет таких требований.

Comment: `Func<T>` - это делегат - указатель на метод. Сигнатура данного делегата совпадает с сигнатурой метода.

Comment: Если создавать делегат в конструкторе, то статика не потребуется

Comment: Можно еще через свойство `Func<int> func => () => Factorial(5);`

Comment: как такое 
Func<int, int> fun = Factorial;
превращается в
Func<int> func = () => Factorial(5);
пытался Factorial в Task запустить. что за делегат в лямбде?

Comment: Как этот комментарий относится к изначальному вопросу?